# How to wrap flex cloumns in a single row for mobile device

Tags: bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have an HTML template and I want to create a simple flex column for my data list. The Tick icon coming to second row on mobile device. I want it in a single row without a line break.

[image]

```
<div class="container disable-text-selection ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <h1>Vehicle</h1>
        <div class="text-zero top-right-button-container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg top-right-button mr-1"> + ADD NEW VEHICLE </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 list" data-check-all="checkAll">
      <div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-3"> 
          <a class="d-flex" href="Pages.Product.Detail.html"> 
            <img src="../../../../assets/img/bike-thumb.jpg" alt="Honda Shine" class="list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left" /> 
          </a>
        <div class="pl-2 d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
          <div class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center"> <br>
            <a href="/app/vehicle" class="w-90 w-sm-50">
                 <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate">Honda Shine </p>
                 <span class="text-muted mb-0">Tysys TCP 2223</span>
            </a>
             <div class="w-10 w-sm-50"> 
                 <a class="d-flex justify-content-end" href="#"> <img src="../../../../assets/img/tick-icon.svg" alt="tick" width="30" class=""/> </a> 
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.card-body` contains the anchor tag pointing to "/app/vehicle" and a div wrapping another anchor tag. If you want the div to be on the same row with the first anchor tag, you need to have the `.card-body` display as flex-row instead of flex-column.

You also want to remove `<br />`.

```html
<div class="card-body d-flex flex-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-center">
    <a href="/app/vehicle" class="w-90 w-sm-50">
        <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate">Honda Shine </p>
        <span class="text-muted mb-0">Tysys TCP 2223</span>
    </a>
    <div class="w-10 w-sm-50"> 
        <a class="d-flex justify-content-end" href="#">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/30" alt="tick" width="30" class=""/>
        </a> 
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/ksg7oz2e/10/

Answer (score 0):

Change `flex-column flex-lg-row` to `flex-row` in card-body.

```
<div class="container disable-text-selection ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="mb-3">
        <h1>Vehicle</h1>
        <div class="text-zero top-right-button-container">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg top-right-button mr-1"> + ADD NEW VEHICLE </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 list" data-check-all="checkAll">
      <div class="card d-flex flex-row mb-3"> 
          <a class="d-flex" href="Pages.Product.Detail.html"> 
            <img src="../../../../assets/img/bike-thumb.jpg" alt="Honda Shine" class="list-thumbnail responsive border-0 card-img-left" /> 
          </a>
        <div class="pl-2 d-flex flex-grow-1 min-width-zero">
          <div class="card-body align-self-center d-flex flex-column flex-lg-row justify-content-between min-width-zero align-items-lg-center"> <br>
            <a href="/app/vehicle" class="w-90 w-sm-50">
                 <p class="list-item-heading mb-0 truncate">Honda Shine </p>
                 <span class="text-muted mb-0">Tysys TCP 2223</span>
            </a>
             <div class="w-10 w-sm-50"> 
                 <a class="d-flex justify-content-end" href="#"> <img src="../../../../assets/img/tick-icon.svg" alt="tick" width="30" class=""/> </a> 
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `display:flex` for mobile device

example like this :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    display:flex !important;
  }
}
```